# How to show branches where a branch is merged to

Tags: git

I have a branch A and multiple branches, for example B,C,D,E
My branch A is merged in some of the exmaple branches. Is there a possibility to show in which of B,C,D,E my branch A is merged? (B,C,D,E can be dynamic, so switching to one of those branches with merge-list is not an option for me)

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

For each of B, C, D, E ... run

> git merge-base A [other branch]

If it returns the same SHA as

> git rev-parse A

it means A's been merged into said branch.

(This is assuming the commit at the tip of A is the commit that was merged in.)

Comment: What if i dont know my other branches? Can't i get a list of branch A where this branch was merged to?